# Check in/out current item in a sharepoint designer reusable workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, check-out, check-in

I am using sharepoint 2013. I have created a reusable worklow. In this workflow I do some logic to publish approval stuff. After I approve the task I got some error that the item is not checked out for editing. So I turned of the option on the list where it is required to check out the item to edit the item. Now it works.

But I would like to add 2 extra actions in my workflow. I would like to start the workflow with "Check out current item" and finish the workflow with "Check in current item".

I found an action which is check in and check out, but I need to select a list and add some filter to select the current item.

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/use-check-out-and-check-in-actions-with-globally-reusable-workflows-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

I found this solution to implement the actions like I would like to have: check in and out the current item.

Isn't there a better solution to check in or out the current item in a sharepoint designer workflow?